# How can I connect remotely without forcing the local user to be disconnected?

Tags: windows, connection

I am trying to remote control a computer running XP Pro SP3 from my laptop running on W8.1. When I connect, I'm told that by connecting I will terminate the local session - something I don't want to do. Is there a way around this limitation?

I found this message from tsilb posted in 2008
"Windows Server editions support one console plus two remote connections simultaneously. When configured as a Terminal Server, they support one per license. All other editions support one total session, local or remote.

"Are the pre-existing connections local or Domain accounts? Look around in the local or group security policies. If Domain, check the user account properties."

...but I'm afraid I don't understand the terminology he has used and so don't know if it is definitely answering my question.

If this is a limitation of RDC, can you recommend an alternative solution that will allow me to connect while leaving the local user logged in?